# Pygame - Loading images in sprites

Tags: python, pygame

How do I load an image into a sprite instead of drawing a shape for the sprite?
Ex: I load a 50x50 image into a sprite instead of drawing a 50x50 rect

Here is my sprite code so far:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, width, height):

        super().__init__()
        #Config
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

            # Draw
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, color , [0, 0, width, height])

        # Fetch
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def right(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x += pixels
    def left(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x -= pixels
    def up(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y -= pixels
    def down(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y += pixels
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First [load](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) the image in the global scope or in a separate module and import it. Don't load it in the `__init__` method, otherwise it has to be read from the hard disk every time you create an instance and that's slow.

Now you can assign the global `IMAGE` in the class (`self.image = IMAGE`) and all instances will reference this image.

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
# The screen/display has to be initialized before you can load an image.
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))

IMAGE = pg.image.load('an_image.png').convert_alpha()


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = IMAGE
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
```

If you want to use different images for the same class, you can pass them during the instantiation:

```
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, image):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)


player1 = Player((100, 300), IMAGE1)
player2 = Player((300, 300), IMAGE2)
```

---

Use the [`convert`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) or `convert_alpha` (for images with transparency) methods to improve the blit performance.

---

If the image is in a subdirectory (for example "images"), construct the path with [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
import os.path
import pygame as pg

IMAGE = pg.image.load(os.path.join('images', 'an_image.png')).convert_alpha()
```

Comment: I copied everything and the images will not appear, therefore the sprites just show up as blank.

Comment: Nvm i got it to work, I needed to remove the colorkey and surface.fill code blocks for it to work, thanks!