# Pygame NameError: name 'image' is not defined

Tags: python, pygame

I'm modifying a program I found online and I am trying to load a .png instead of the previous block sprite, but I think I am coding it incorrectly when trying to load it. Here is the code:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """
    This class represents the bar at the bottom that the player controls.
    """

    # -- Methods
    def __init__(self):
        """ Constructor function """

        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
        image.self.pygame ("Sprite-01.png")

        # Set a referance to the image rect.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Set speed vector of player
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

        # List of sprites we can bump against
        self.level = None
```

And this is the Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   

File "C:/Users/1234/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/class 10 program St.Patrick.py", line 452, in <module>
    main()   
File "C:/Users/1234/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/class 10 program St.Patrick.py", line 360, in main
    player = Player()   
File "C:/Users/1234/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/class 10 program St.Patrick.py", line 51, in __init__
    image.self.pygame ("Sprite-01.png") 
NameError: name 'image' is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
image.self.pygame ("Sprite-01.png")
```

Change that line to:

```
self.image = pygame.image.load("Sprite-01.png").convert_alpha()
```

or just `.convert()` if the image has no transparent parts.

I also recommend loading the images in the global scope or another module before the program starts and then just reuse them instead of loading them again. Reading from the hard disk is slow.

Comment: Now I'm getting this:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/1234/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/class 10 program St.Patrick.py", line 452, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/1234/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/class 10 program St.Patrick.py", line 360, in main
    player = Player()
  File "C:/Users/1234/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/class 10 program St.Patrick.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.image = pygame.image.load("Sprite-01.png").convert_alpha()
pygame.error: Couldn't open Sprite-01.png

Comment: You have to pass the correct path. In which directory is the image? And check if the image name is correct.

Comment: Here I describe how you can construct the path: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47082774/6220679 You could also just do `"images/Sprite-01.png"` if the image is in an 'images' directory.

Comment: Do you mean my pictures?

Comment: If the file is in a 'pictures' directory in the directory that contains your .py file, you have to pass `"pictures/Sprite-01.png"` to `pygame.image.load`.

Comment: I am clearly not cut out for this at my skill level.

Comment: It also doesn't held that I have a crudy computer.

Comment: Still no success?

Comment: Try to put the "Sprite-01.png" file into the same directory as your .py file that you use to start the game and then try to load it with `self.image = pygame.image.load("Sprite-01.png").convert_alpha()` again.

Comment: at start try to use full path to images with `C:/Users/1234/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/` and later you can find question/answer like "how to find full path to folder with script" (it uses `sys.argv[0]`) and then you can use it to create full path to images automatically.