# How to assign a sprite (image) to a rect?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'm trying to learn how to create a maze game using python and pygame for a project. The problem I'm having is that in all the examples I find they just have a simple square as the character. I've got a image (the character sprite I want to use) that is 16x16px so it's the correct size for the example I'm working with, and I've even managed to get the sprite to load once. But when It did my character couldn't move...

So how do I get this rect to be represented as the 16x16px image that I have stored in the same folder as my code instead of a colored square?

These are the 2 areas which I give me results when trying to change the player sprite:

```
class Player(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(32, 32, 16, 16)
```

```
    for wall in walls:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), wall.rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), end_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 200, 0), player.rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

(Updated) Full game:

```
import os
import random
import pygame

IMAGE = pygame.image.load('mudkip.png')
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()


# Class for character

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos):

        super().__init__(all_sprites)
        # Get the image from the variable
        self.image = IMAGE
        # Get the rect from the image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def move(self, dx, dy):

        # Move each axis separately. Note that this checks for collisions both times.
        if dx != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(dx, 0)
        if dy != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(0, dy)

    def move_single_axis(self, dx, dy):

        # Move the rect
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy

        # If you collide with a wall, move out based on velocity
        for wall in walls:
            if self.rect.colliderect(wall.rect):
                if dx > 0:  # Moving right; Hit the left side of the wall
                    self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
                if dx < 0:  # Moving left; Hit the right side of the wall
                    self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
                if dy > 0:  # Moving down; Hit the top side of the wall
                    self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
                if dy < 0:  # Moving up; Hit the bottom side of the wall
                    self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom


# Nice class to hold a wall rect
class Wall(object):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        walls.append(self)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 16, 16)


# Initialise pygame
os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
pygame.init()

# Set up the display
pygame.display.set_caption("Get to the red square!")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((560, 240))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
walls = []  # List to hold the walls
player = Player((30, 30))  # Create the player

# Holds the level layout in a list of strings.
level = [
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    "W    W                            W",
    "W    W      WWWWWW                W",
    "W   WWWW       W                  W",
    "W   W        WWWW       wwwwww    W",
    "W WWW  WWWW                       W",
    "W   W     W W                     W",
    "WE  W     W   WWW W               W",
    "W   WWW WWW   W W                 W",
    "W     W   W   W W                 W",
    "WWW   W   WWWWW W                 W",
    "W W      WW           WWWWWWWWW   W",
    "W W   WWWW   WWW                  W",
    "W     W        W                  W",
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
]

# Parse the level string above. W = wall, E = exit
x = y = 0
for row in level:
    for col in row:
        if col == "W":
            Wall((x, y))
        if col == "E":
            end_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 16, 16)
        x += 16
    y += 16
    x = 0

running = True
while running:

    clock.tick(60)

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running = False

    # Move the player if an arrow key is pressed
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player.move(-2, 0)
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player.move(2, 0)
    if key[pygame.K_UP]:
        player.move(0, -2)
    if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        player.move(0, 2)

    # Just added this to make it slightly fun ;)
    if player.rect.colliderect(end_rect):
        raise SystemExit('You win!')

    # Draw the scene
    all_sprites.draw(0)
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for wall in walls:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), wall.rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), end_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Error with all_sprites.draw():

```
all_sprites.draw()
TypeError: draw() missing 1 required positional argument: 'surface'
```

Error with all_sprites.draw(0):

```
line 129, in <module>
    all_sprites.draw(0)
lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 474, in draw
    surface_blit = surface.blit
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'blit'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pygame - Loading images in sprites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082209/pygame-loading-images-in-sprites)

Comment: official domunentation for [pygame.image.load](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) - it gives you `Surface` with image which you can display with `screen.blit(surface, rect)` BTW: after loadin image you can do `rect = surface.get_rect()` to create `rect` with image's size.

Comment: @Pygasm So I've add the image and a sprite class but it still loads a square. I need to change something in the Player object and draw area that I shared but I can't work out what I need to change. Here's what I have at the moment: https://pastebin.com/jLFnv3JK

Comment: Please don't put your code within a comment. Click the 'Edit' button on your post and add it yourself. @MikeS

Comment: @MikeS Sorry about that, I've got a pastebin now: https://pastebin.com/jLFnv3JK 
I appreciate you helping but I'm really struggling to understand how I apply the sprite to my character once I've made it.

Comment: @MikeS I can't exactly access pastebin at the moment so I cannot help you unless you can wait for several hours, or if you edit the code into the original question by clicking the "Edit" button that is right below the text of your question.

Comment: @Pygasm Ok I've edited it in :)

Comment: @MikeS Wrote a question, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so the first thing you will need is to load an image in, which it looks like you have already done.

To put that *in* your sprite, you have to do this:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos): # Additional position argument, formatted like (x, y)
        # Get the image from the variable
        self.image = IMAGE

        # Get the rect from the image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
```

Then later, you add a `draw` function that adds your character to the screen. Its relatively simple.

```
def draw(self):
    screen.blit(self.image, self.rect) 
    # Note, you may have move your global vars before the sprite classes to prevent a NameError now.
```

Finally, you put them both together with some added things to get your new base class to add things onto later.

Youre not supposed to add `def draw` to the main game loop ;)

```
# Earlier in the code...
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group() # This will allow all the sprites to be drawn in one fell swoop instead of it being done manually.

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite): # Make sure to inherit the sprite object!

    def __init__(self, pos):

        super().__init__(all_sprites) # Add the new sprite to the sprite group
        self.image = IMAGE

        # Get the rect from the image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

# Then in the game loop...
all_sprites.draw() # This will call draw() in every active sprite object.
```

Comment: I added a position argument (self, pos(0, 0)): and I get a syntax error. 
If I don't add it I also get an error asking for them. I'm so useless, thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: When I meant an argument, I meant that the pos would remain as a placeholder within the class code, but when *constructing* the class, you would pass an argument into those parenthesis, so `player = Player((0, 0))`, not `(self, pos(0,0)`. BTW: Changing `pos` will also change where the player will appear, so make sure the value lines up where you want it to be! ;) @MikeS

Comment: I've given my player a pos value now and don't get any errors anymore. Problem is my player is invisible. I know the player is still there because I can hit the ending point, but you have to guess where your character is. I've updated the post with the part I changed. If I remove the draw.rect or replace it with the screen.blit I have no sprite at all, If I leave it in my players back to being a colored square. Adding the screen.blit doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @MikeS Made an edit, youre not supposed to add `draw()` to the main game loop, but the sprite. Also forgot that sprite groups need to exist so I added that in too.

Comment: I've tried playing around to fix it but I'm stuck again... It says it takes exactly one argument when I run the game. I've tried removing one set of brackets from the create player function and then it says it needs "2 positional arguments but 3 were given" even though I've got (30,30). I've added the errors to the post. I do realise your pretty much writing this for me but I had no experience with Pygame before this and your explanations have been really helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: @MikeS Oh. I was assuming that you were already inheriting `pygame.sprite.Sprite`. Edit made.

Comment: Still getting the one argument error. I've updated the code. Have I gotten confused because the Player sprite and Player object both start off the same?

Comment: @MikeS Can you recombine all your new code into your post again? Its hard for me to keep up now.

Comment: Yeah, I've updated the full game section so it has all my code right now.

Comment: You have to change `class Player(object)` to `class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite)`.

Comment: @Pygame Then I have 2 areas that are mostly the same don't I? My 2 areas that are commented "Character sprite" and "Class for character" both have the same code except the "Class for character" area has more underneath. Anyway, If I run the code I get: draw() missing 1 required positional argument: 'surface'. I tried removing the "Character Sprite" area in case I'm getting confused and still got the same error so maybe it's redundant. I'll edit my post to show you the 2 areas I mean, I also copied the comments across so it's more obvious that they're the same.

Comment: Remove the class that is under `# Character Sprite`, its most likely redundant. Use the class that is under `# Class for character`. The redundant class does not have `draw()` so python will not be able to run it.

Comment: Ok now the all_sprites.draw() is playing up. I've updated the post with errors.

Comment: `all_sprites.draw()` has no arguments, don't put a 0 there. @MikeS

Comment: But If I don't give it an argument I get an error asking for one. See the first error near the bottom of my post @Pygasm

Comment: @MikeS Try putting your `screen` variable inside `all_sprites.draw()`

Comment: @Pygams Yes, it's finally working! The character was leaving a trail behind itself like when you'd drag a window around on a slow Windows PC, but I moved the screen.fill((0, 0, 0)) to the bottom and I finally have it working. Thanks so much for your help, you're a savior :)

Comment: @MikeS Youre welcome, didn't expect to teach someone how to create a fully fledged sprite objects but here I am. You can check out the [Pygame Docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/) in order to learn more stuff [and to minimize the amount of questions you need to ask here!]

Comment: @Pygame Thanks, I'll take a look.